# bar width by units and symbolic x coords not getting along

Tags: pgfplots, luatex

I'm trying to make a stacked bar graph with the bars at full width and symbolic x coords. Here's a minimalish example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,left=15mm,right=15mm,top=-8mm,bottom=10mm,headheight=3cm,headsep=15mm,marginparsep=0mm,marginparwidth=0mm,footskip=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect]
\begin{axis}[
ybar stacked,
bar width=1,
symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(a, 39.000000)
(b, 30.200000)
(c, 39.000000)
(d, 30.200000)
(e, 33.300000)
(f, 30.000000)
(g, 32.900000)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, when I try to complile this with lualatex, I get

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `\pgfplots@loc@TMPa ' has
>    not been defined with 'symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g}... Maybe it has been 
>   misspelled? Or did you mean something like [normalized]\pgfplots@loc@TMPa ?.

which I haven't found overly helpful.

What works:

1. an absolute value for bar width (or no bar width at all)
2. no symbolic x coords, replace a..g by 1..7.

So now I'm out of things to try. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I consider this being a bug which I reported as bug 147 in the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/147/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem starts here:

> ```
> \def\pgfplots@bar@mathparse@#1#2{%
>   \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/#2}}%
>   \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared
>   \else
>       \edef\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@{#1}%
>       \if N\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@%
>           \if a\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice
>           \else
>               \if x\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice
>                   \def\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@{y}%
>               \else
>                   \if y\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice
>                       \def\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@{x}%
>                   \else
>                       \pgfplotsthrow{invalid argument}{\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@}{Sorry, the value of 'bar direction' is invalid}\pgfeov%
>                   \fi
>               \fi
>           \fi
>       \fi
>       \if N\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@%
>           \pgfplots@bar@mathparse@error{#1}{#2}%
>       \else
>           \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPa=\pgfmathresult
>           % ↓↓↓ notice this line ↓↓↓
>           \csname pgfplotstransformdirection\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@\endcsname{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
>           % ↑↑↑ notice this line ↑↑↑
>           \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPa=\pgfmathresult
>           \if\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@ x%   
>               \pgfqpointxy@orig{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}{0}%
>               \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}%
>           \else
>               \pgfqpointxy@orig{0}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
>               \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@y}%
>           \fi
>           %\edef\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@y}}%
>           %\expandafter\pgfmathveclen@\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
>       \fi
>   \fi
> }%
> ```

By using this macro, [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) will calculate the correct width of ybars, especially if the width is given in relative value.

This is why you can see `\csname pgfplotstransformdirection ...` in the code. This macro is defined by `x coord trafo` or so. It will translate the input x-coordinate to physical coordinate. Usually the input is a number, (`1.2`); sometimes it is a date (`2017-1-23`); in your case it should be symbolic (`b`).

But your input is `1`, which is not a pre-defined symbolic coordinate, so you see the error.

To get over this, one cannot simply pass `bar width=b` because `\pgfmathparse` does not know what is `b`. Some possible solutions include:

- wait until the package updates; or
- redefined `\pgfplots@bar@mathparse@` by replacing the transform line by

```
        % ↓↓↓ notice this line ↓↓↓
        \csname pgfplotstransformdirection\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@\endcsname{[normalized]\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%  
        % ↑↑↑ notice this line ↑↑↑
```

And this is even better

```
        \ifx\pgfplots@symb@magic@prefix\undefined % test if symbolic coordinate
            \csname pgfplotstransformdirection\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@\endcsname{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
        \else
            \csname pgfplotstransformdirection\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@\endcsname{[normalized]\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
        \fi
```

## An MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\pgfplots@bar@mathparse@#1#2{%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/#2}}%
    \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared
    \else
        \edef\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@{#1}%
        \if N\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@%
            \if a\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice
            \else
                \if x\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice
                    \def\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@{y}%
                \else
                    \if y\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice
                        \def\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@{x}%
                    \else
                        \pgfplotsthrow{invalid argument}{\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@}{Sorry, the value of 'bar direction' is invalid}\pgfeov%
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
        \if N\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@%
            \pgfplots@bar@mathparse@error{#1}{#2}%
        \else
            \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPa=\pgfmathresult
            \ifx\pgfplots@symb@magic@prefix\undefined
                \csname pgfplotstransformdirection\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@\endcsname{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
            \else
                \csname pgfplotstransformdirection\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@\endcsname{[normalized]\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
            \fi
            \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPa=\pgfmathresult
            \if\pgfplots@bar@direction@choice@ x%   
                \pgfqpointxy@orig{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}{0}%
                \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}%
            \else
                \pgfqpointxy@orig{0}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
                \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@y}%
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        bar width=1,
        symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (a, 39.000000)
        (b, 30.200000)
        (c, 39.000000)
        (d, 30.200000)
        (e, 33.300000)
        (f, 30.000000)
        (g, 32.900000)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        bar width=1,
        xticklabels={a,b,c,d,e,f,g},
        xtick=data, % a tick for each bar
        typeset ticklabels with strut % all xticklabels on the same baseline
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1, 39.000000)
        (2, 30.200000)
        (3, 39.000000)
        (4, 30.200000)
        (5, 33.300000)
        (6, 30.000000)
        (7, 32.900000)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on pgfplots by any means, but I found a workaround to this issue in cmhughes's answer to a different question: [Formatting a pgfplot graph. Thicker bars and total width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47885/91770)

Instead of using `symbolic y coords={A, B, C}`, one can instead specify `ytick={0,1,2}` and `yticklabels={A, B, C}` which doesn't lead to the same problem when setting `bar width`. Of course, all the coordinates in the `\addplot` lines must be changed to the appropriate numbers instead of the symbols.

Modifying the MWE given in the question appropriately:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,left=15mm,right=15mm,top=-8mm,bottom=10mm,headheight=3cm,headsep=15mm,marginparsep=0mm,marginparwidth=0mm,footskip=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect]
\begin{axis}[
ybar stacked,
bar width=0.8,
xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
xticklabels={a,b,c,d,e,f,g},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(0, 39.000000)
(1, 30.200000)
(2, 39.000000)
(3, 30.200000)
(4, 33.300000)
(5, 30.000000)
(6, 32.900000)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]